# python dict in formatted string

Tags: python, dictionary, string-formatting

I want to write a python dictionary in a string. The values of the items should be give by the formatted string.

I expected the following to work, but it doesnt because the first '{' used to define the dict is interpreted as a formated field

```
In: "{'key_1': '{value}'}".format(**{'value': 'test'})
```

the following works fine, but doesn't return the expected dict:

```
In: "'key_1': '{value}'".format(**{'value': 'test'})
Out: "'key_1': 'test'"
```

one way to overcome the problem is by using list brakets and replace them later by the dict brakets:

```
In: "['key_1': '{value}']".format(**{'value': 'test'}).replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}')
Out: "{'key_1': 'test'}"
```

How to write this in a better way?

Comment: You should look at Python's `json` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double `{{`and `}}`:

```
 "{{'key_1': '{value}'}}".format(**{'value': 'test'})
```